# How to get dummies in complicated condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe below

```
   col  
A  a
A  b
A  c
B  d
B  e
C  f
```

I would like to get dummy variable

```
   a b c d e f 
A  1 1 1 0 0 0 
B  0 0 0 1 1 0  
C  0 0 0 0 0 1
```

How can I get this?

I tried

`df.col.get_dummies()`

But I couldnt groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by index and aggregate `max`:

```
print (df.col.str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).max())
   a  b  c  d  e  f
A  1  1  1  0  0  0
B  0  0  0  1  1  0
C  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Or:

```
print (pd.get_dummies(df.col).groupby(level=0).max())
   a  b  c  d  e  f
A  1  1  1  0  0  0
B  0  0  0  1  1  0
C  0  0  0  0  0  1
```